# How to place comments_template(); outside the loop?

Tags: loop, comments-template, outside-wordpress

I am making a new template and I need to place the comments template outside the wordpress loop and just above the footer in the single.php file.

I searched on google and the best answered I could find related to my issue is in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384205/displaying-the-wordpress-comments-template-outside-the-loop

However, that did not work.
The same comments are appearing on all posts.

So, how can I display the comments display outsite the wp loop?

EDIT: This is the single.php file

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content-single', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <nav class="nav-single">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
                <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?></span>
                <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' ); ?></span>
            </nav><!-- .nav-single -->



        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<div id="secondary" class="sidebar-area" role="complementary">
    <?php get_sidebar(secondary); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->

<?php
comments_template( '', true );
?>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post whatever code you have right now that isn't working.

Comment: ok I just edited the post to include the code.

Comment: Next, double-check that you've got comments enabled for whatever post you'd trying to use and that you're looking at something that uses the `single.php` template.

Comment: Yes, comments are enabled for the post I am looking at. The problem here is that the comments_template is showing up but the comments that are made appear on all posts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, after some research I came up with the solution. The solution is for displaying wordpress comments outside the loop and as a bonus how to place disqus comments outside the loop as well.

**First, How to place wordpress comments outside the loop:**

In single.php we need to define a new global variable for storing the post id (place this inside the loop)

```
global $postid;
$postid = get_the_ID();
```

Then, we can place the list of comments outside the loop with the following code:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php    
        //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
        $comments = get_comments(array(
            'post_id' => $postid,
            'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
        ));

        //Display the list of comments
        wp_list_comments(array(
            'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
            'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
        ), $comments);

    ?>
</ol>
```

You can as well place the comment form and pass the post id as follows:

```
<?php comment_form( $args, $postid ); ?>
```

**For DISQUS:**

In single.php, We need to define a second variable to get the post title (place this inside the loop):

```
global $dposttitle;
$dposttitle = wp_title( '', false);
```

And then add the following call wherever you want to display your disqus comments:

In your child's theme functions add the following:

```
function disqus_embed($disqus_shortname, $postid, $dposttitle) {
    global $post;
    wp_enqueue_script('disqus_embed','http://'.$disqus_shortname.'.disqus.com/embed.js');
    echo '<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_shortname = "'.$disqus_shortname.'";
        var disqus_title = "'.$dposttitle.'";
        var disqus_url = "'.get_permalink($postid).'";
        var disqus_identifier = "'.$disqus_shortname.'-'.$postid.'";
    </script>';
}
```

Finally, call disqus_embed outside the loop in single.php

```
disqus_embed($disqus_shortname, $postid, $dposttitle);
```

Please feel free to tell me if there is a better way to implement this.